# A variable which is recognised in one line is is not recognised two lines later

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
chosenCategory[i] = questionsCats[randomCat].category;
console.log(chosenCategory[i]); 
console.log(questionCats[randomCat].category;
```

This is three consecutive lines of code. In the second line, the log shows that the previous line worked and therefore that questionCats[randomCat].category was found. In the last line I get an error - Uncaught ReferenceError: questionCats is not defined
    at initStart().

How is it possible that after doing nothing except reading it, it is suddenly undefined and how do I resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: You have no bracket ending in the last line

Comment: is error gone after placing `)`?

Comment: You provided a code out of the context that's making the error happen. Is there any loop around this code? Are the lines inside an async function where so much things can change before the codes are processed by the compiler. JS Compiler work in Context/SubContext for code execution and scope. We need to get in which context the codes are being used.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you might need to be more explicit with the codes and show the ouside context of your codes.

Mean while you have 2 errors in your codes:

1. Missing closing parenthese
2. Typo in the variable, you checked on `questionsCats` on the 1st line, and ask for `questionCats` on the last line

The 3rd line in codes should be with `questionsCats`:

```
chosenCategory[i] = questionsCats[randomCat].category;
console.log(chosenCategory[i]); 
console.log(questionsCats[randomCat].category);
```

1 TIP: Consider that the Compiler is always right. So when it says `questionCats is not defined at initStart().`, take it as:

*Well I did not have a variable name `questionCats` in that function, or maybe I made some typo in it.*

Comment: questionsCats! Thanks folks. I can't believe how many times I must have missed that while trying to find the error.

Comment: @HilaryWoodccock-Reynolds That happens to everyone. Hopefully it was only that at this time. Good work with the rest!